# get the row number in a table with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table added dynamically to my page.

```js
$("#myTable").on("click", "tr .eliminar.tooltip", function() {
  var myCol = $("#myTable").index(); //ok
  var $tr = $("#myTable").closest('tr'); // ok
  var myRow = $tr.index(); // wrong value
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="uk-table" id="myTable">

  <tbody>
    <tr data-myData="001">
      <td>
        <a class="editar tooltip">
          <img src="Editar.png">
        </a>
        <a class="eliminar tooltip">
          <img src="Eliminar.png">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-myData="002">
      <td>
        <a class="editar tooltip">
          <img src="Editar.png">
        </a>
        <a class="eliminar tooltip">
          <img src="Eliminar.png">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I get the info?
when clicking, I want to get the row number to get the data.attr("myData").

Thats the jquery code:

Comment: *"I want to get the row number to get the data*" - so you don't need the row number at all?  Just the data?   http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `this` i.e. current element context to get the `tr` element and 
[`.index(element)`](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element)

```
$("#myTable").on("click", "tr .eliminar.tooltip", function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var myRow = $("#myTable tr").index($tr);
    var myData = $tr.attr('data-myData')
    console.log(myRow, myData);
});
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#myTable").on("click", "tr .eliminar.tooltip", function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var myRow = $("#myTable tr").index($tr);
    var myData = $tr.attr('data-myData')
    console.log(myRow, myData);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="uk-table" id="myTable">

  <tbody>
    <tr data-myData="001">
      <td>
        <a class="editar tooltip">
          <img src="Editar.png">
        </a>
        <a class="eliminar tooltip">
          <img src="Eliminar.png">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-myData="002">
      <td>
        <a class="editar tooltip">
          <img src="Editar.png">
        </a>
        <a class="eliminar tooltip">
          <img src="Eliminar.png">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Get COLUMN INDEX on click:

```
$(this).closest("td").index();
```

Get ROW INDEX on click:

```
$(this).closest("tr").index();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to target each tr using the .closest() function based on the td clicked. And using the .attr() function to get the value of "data-myData"

```
var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
var data = tr.attr("data-myData");
```

I have made a fiddle as an example.

https://jsfiddle.net/gpo0htp5/

Comment: To make it clear where to put this code, add the click handler.  Also, you can use `.data("myData")`.